# CSS3 Transform Skew (um canto)

Tags: html, css, css3

É possível personalizar para deixar como dessa imagem? https://s3.envato.com/files/127249204/screenshots/screenshot%20(114).png

Eu encontrei uma solução, mas não é útil para mim, pois não ficou igual ao da tabela.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

.div2 {
 border-top: 80px solid #3498db;
    border-right: 30px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
    height: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin:50px 0;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="div2"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acho que você pode fazer desta forma, o único problema que vejo é na questão da responsividade.

```css
.div2 {
  background:#3498db;
  height: 80px;
  width: 250px;
  position:relative;
}

.div2:after {
  position:absolute;
  bottom:-20px;
  content:" ";
  border-left: 250px solid #3498db;
  border-bottom: 20px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0);
}
```

```html
<div class="div2"></div>
```

Comment: Show, era isso mesmo valew =D

Answer (score 0):

Consegui com uma forma alternativa. Usando `Skew` e `Translate`. Vê se te adianta! :)

```css
#container {
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 250px;
  height: 80px;
}

#container div {
  background: #3498db;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  transform: skewY(-5deg) translateY(-12px);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Funcionou também, valew =D